# How do I have text between two < > (like in this photo)?

Tags: css

How do I have a paragraph in between two photos that are like < > (see photo example)? Photos are like rectangles, so how do I fit something in the space between?

This is what I'd like to do:

[image: example]

Comment: Well pretty much this can be done in many different ways. One way is, have those <> as images (svg for example, google for them), have them positioned absoulte and parent div relative. Look into element positioning with css to understand it better.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nemanja G, how do I do that though without the text overlapping the <>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically wouldn't answer considering you showed no effort, but I was interested in throwing this together.

So, you could easily use flexbox and create a container wrapping 3 parts. I am using `$lt;` and `&gt;` for the chevrons, but you could put images in that div as well if you wanted.

```css
.chevron-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   max-width: 250px;
}
.chevron-icon {
   display: flex;
   align-self: center;
   font-size: 60px;
}
.chevron-text {
   display: flex;
   align-self: center;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron-container">
   <div class="chevron-icon">&lt</div>
   <div class="chevron-text">
       This Is My Sentence Between Two Chevrons. 
   </div>
   <div class="chevron-icon">&gt</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know I was supposed to do that, I will keep that in to consideration for next time. However, how do I put it in between the chevrons without them overlapping with the text? I'd like the text to actually be in between the up and down of the chevrons, like in the image.

Comment: This example doesn't overlap. Are you saying you want to the text to overlap?

Comment: The result with your example looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/mPhYMqr
I want to actually be in between them like in my image, but I don't want the text to overlap

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code:**

```
<h2>I will display</h2>
```

**Style:**

```
h2:after {content: ' \003E';}
h2:before{content: ' \003C';}
```

you can add your own design too.